# SQL with numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to build a loop with SQL Server.

When I execute `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3;` SQL Server creates a table with 1 column and 4 rows.

Can anyone think of a way to achive the same however without using `UNION`?

Comment: You might want to provide a sample output that you are expecting. Also, you probably need to clarify if the output required is just a simple table with rows containing a sequence of numbers or if the final output needs other columns in it.

Comment: You're trying to build a loop, and then you just ask about a statement that returns 4 numbers (or actually 3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `values()` table constructor:

```
select *
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4)) v(n);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with a recursive cte.

```
declare @max int=4

;with cte as
(
    select 1 as val
    union all
    select val+1
    from cte
    where val < @max
)
select *
from cte
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few common options to do this in case your use case expands hundreds or thousands of rows...

Commonly seen a a tally table...

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Or, using a function from Jeff Moden

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTallyProg]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Given a start value, end value, and increment, create a sequencial list of integers.
 Programmers Notes:
 1. The increment can be negative if the start value is greater than the end value. In other words, it can count down
    as well as up.

 Revison History:
 Rev 00 - 18 Feb 2017 - Jeff Moden
        - Rewrite original to take start, end, and increment parameters.
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (
         @pStart     BIGINT
        ,@pEnd       BIGINT
        ,@pIncrement BIGINT
        )
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN WITH 
 E01(N)   AS (SELECT NULL FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))E0(N)) --10 rows
,E04(N)   AS (SELECT NULL FROM E01 a CROSS JOIN E01 b CROSS JOIN E01 c CROSS JOIN E01 d) --10 Thousand rows
,E16(N)   AS (SELECT NULL FROM E04 a CROSS JOIN E04 b CROSS JOIN E04 c CROSS JOIN E04 d) --10 Quadrillion rows, which is crazy
,Tally(N) AS (SELECT TOP (ABS((@pEnd-@pStart+@pIncrement)/@pIncrement))
                     N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                FROM E16
               WHERE (@pStart<=@pEnd AND @pIncrement > 0)
                  OR (@pStart>=@pEnd AND @pIncrement < 0)
               ORDER BY N
             )
      SELECT TOP (ABS((@pEnd-@pStart+@pIncrement)/@pIncrement))
             N = (t.N-1)*@pIncrement+@pStart
        FROM Tally t
       ORDER BY t.N
;
GO
```

Or, another quick function by JL

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tfn_Tally]
(
@NumOfRows BIGINT = 1000000 
,@StartWith BIGINT = 1563984
)
/* ============================================================================
07/20/2017 JL, Created. Capable of creating a sequense of rows 
                ranging from -10,000,000,000,000,000 to 10,000,000,000,000,000
============================================================================ */
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
RETURN
WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10 rows
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100 rows
        cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),                             -- 10,000 rows
        cte_n4 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b),                             -- 100,000,000 rows
        cte_Tally (n) AS (
            SELECT TOP (@NumOfRows)
                (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) + @StartWith
            FROM 
                cte_n4 a CROSS JOIN cte_n4 b                                                    -- 10,000,000,000,000,000 rows
            )
    SELECT 
        t.n
    FROM 
        cte_Tally t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can use an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Declare @N int =4

Select Top (@N) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
 From  master..spt_values n1
```

**Returns**

```
N
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a sequence of values to be joined to another table later on, I would strongly suggest to create a one time auxiliary table of numbers as described [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

The code to generate such table is pretty basic:

```
SELECT TOP (1000000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(n)
```

That will created a persisted "Numbers" table in your db that then you can use to join to other tables or use from functions.